# pid provider matching processes that come and go in dtrace

Tags: macos, dtrace

I would like to trace all function calls for a given library in a process, but the process is going to exit and re-open regularly, and I want to keep tracing.

I am doing this now:

```
oneshot$target:LIBRARY::entry
{
    printf("%s\n", probefunc);
}
```

However, this only lets me provide one pid at a time. Can I keep this going?

I want something like:

```
*:LIBRARY::entry
/execname == "foo"/
```

but that * doesn't work there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with just a single dtrace script.  You'd need two (at least...).  And you need to have the ability to run the destructive `system()` action, which most likely means `root` access.

Assume you want to run this script on any new `ls` process:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

pid$1:libc::entry
{
    printf( "func: %s\n", probefunc );
}
```

Assuming the path to that script is `/root/dtrace/tracelibc.d`, the following script will start `dtrace` on any new `ls` process that gets started.  Note that you need `#pragma D option destructive` to be able to start `dtrace` on the new process:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive
#pragma D option quiet

proc:::exec-success
/ "ls" == basename( execname ) /
{
    printf( "tracing process %d\n", pid );
    system( "/root/dtrace/tracelibc.d %d", pid );
}
```

That should work, but in this case `ls` is such a short-lived process that something like this happens quite often:

```
dtrace: failed to compile script /root/dtrace/tracelibc.d: line 10:
    failed to grab process 12289
```

The process is gone by the time `dtrace` gets going.  If you're tracing long-lived processes and don't care that you might miss the first few probes because `dtrace` takes a while to attach, you're done.

But, if you want to trace short-lived processes, you need to stop the process right when it starts, then restart it after `dtrace` attaches:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive
#pragma D option quiet

proc:::exec-success
/ "ls" == basename( execname ) /
{
    printf( "stopping process %d\n", pid );
    system( "/root/dtrace/tracelibc.d %d", pid );
    stop();
}
```

and start it back up in `tracelibc.d`:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive

BEGIN
{
    system( "prun %d", $1 );
}

pid$1:libc::entry
{
    printf( "func: %s\n", probefunc );
}
```

Note that I'm using Solaris `prun` to restart the stopped process.  You'd have to look at the Mac `dtrace` documentation for the `stop()` call to get the Mac equivalent of Solaris `prun`.

But...  ooops.  The two scripts above combine to produce:

```
stopping process 12274
dtrace: failed to compile script /root/dtrace/tracelibc.d: line 10:
    probe description pid12274:libc::entry does not match any probes
```

Why does this say `pid12274:libc::entry` doesn't match any probes?  Oh, yeah - when `exec` returns, the `libc.so` shared object hasn't been loaded into memory yet.  We need a probe that's guaranteed to exist in the target process, and that gets called after `libc.so` is loaded, but before any processing gets done.  `main` should suffice.  So the main script to start it all becomes:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive
#pragma D option quiet

proc:::exec-success
/ "ls" == basename( execname ) /
{
    printf( "stopping process %d\n", pid );
    system( "/root/dtrace/tracemain.d %d", pid );
    stop();
}
```

That starts the `tracemain.d` script, that restarts the process, loads the `tracelibc.d` script, and stops the process again:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive
#pragma D option quiet

BEGIN
{
    system( "prun %d", $1 );
}

pid$1::main:entry
{
    system( "/root/dtrace/tracelibc.d %d", $1 );
    stop();
    /* this instance of dtrace is now done */
    exit( 0 );
}
```

And `tracelibc.d` adds its own `system( "prun %d", $1 );` in the `BEGIN` probe, and it looks like:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option destructive

BEGIN
{
    system( "prun %d", $1 );
}

pid$1:libc::entry
{
    printf( "func: %s\n", probefunc );
}
```

Those three *really* slow up the `ls` process, but they do produce the expected output - and there's a lot of it, as expected.